# Installing Linux on my ASUS ROG G751JT-T7005H

Tags: linux, system-installation, opensuse

I've got a new question. This time about my new Laptop. I wanted to install Linux openSUSE, but it doesn't work. I worked with the Internet, and did everything as described there. I disabled Fast Boot and Secure Boot, enabled the "Launch CSM" option, and so on. All in the Setup. But if I try to boot from my USB-Stick, a message appears: "No system detected, please insert a bootable system and press any key." (Or something like that). Can you help me?

Thanks, Me :)

Comment: Hi there, maybe some details might help answer this. What version and media of openSUSE did you use? The one from https://software.opensuse.org/132/en ? How did you create the USB stick in particular? Any of the recommendations from https://en.opensuse.org/Live_USB_stick ?

Comment: I downloaded the latest stable Version ( I think 13.2) and created the USB with the Universal USB Installer. That went good in the past ( on my old Laptop). But the problem is that the USB-Stick isn't in my Setup, so I can't choose it to boot. But I'm not a geek (yet), so I cannot be sure about these ⬆️ facts.

Comment: Can you test that usb stick on one or more other box(es) to see if it works at all?

Comment: Yes, on my last Laptop, all worked. I tested it twice, one time with another USB, for testing if UUI works, and all went fine. So, I don't know what the problem is...

Comment: Not sure if you got this working?  I was able to boot from usb using the UEFI menu (to access this, hold down the shift key while clicking restart).  there are some options for choosing alternate boot methods there.